# Change the Android app notification bar color

Tags: feature-request, design, stack-overflow-app

While using the Stack Overflow Android app, it is hard to see the notification and status bar icons. By default the icons in the notification bar are white and the app's background color is not much dark.

[image: SO android app]

But while using the Stack Exchange Android app the icons are visible perfectly.

[image: SE android app]

Comment: I think that depends on the header bar color which is the same as the website and mobile web site..

Comment: I think the toolbar color is not explicitly set (for Android at least) so it's sort of opaque and the header color comes through it.

Comment: The app's theme in its manifest can be improved by adding `android:windowLightStatusBar`. It's conveniently explained answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31963003/5742625).

Comment: The StackOverflow app could also choose a dedicated `colorPrimary` and `colorPrimaryDark` to avoid this lack of contrast.

Comment: I think this depends on your device's android version. Icons turn to dark gray and are perfectly visible for me.

Comment: Screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/rNOFKqr.png